# Find pod/VM instance that is serving behind kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, redis, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a legacy system (the guy who build it has resigned and can not be contacted). So it is microservice app hosted in GKE. There is one particular service that is quite strange.
This is a redis service (as the other pods who use this service via its internal IP address can use the redis service and do the redis PING-PONG). However, I see that there are no pods for this service 0/0. Any idea how this could happen?

The YAML file of the service is below:

I don't see any services, deployments, nor pods called node-1, node-2, nor node-3 in our kubernetes cluster. SO it is quite strange for me.
Anyone knows about this?

I have read kubernetes documentation and googled for solutions but I could not find any explanation.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/change-cause":"kubectl apply --record=true --filename=production/svc/dispatchcache-shard-service.yaml"},"name":"dispatchcache-shard","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"node-1","port":7000,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":7000},{"name":"node-2","port":7001,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":7000},{"name":"node-3","port":7002,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":7000}],"type":"ClusterIP"}}
    kubernetes.io/change-cause: kubectl apply --record=true --filename=production/svc/dispatchcache-shard-service.yaml
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-03T08:11:41Z
  name: dispatchcache-shard
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "297308103"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/dispatchcache-shard
  uid: f55bd4d0-c6e3-11e8-9489-42010af00219
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.171.255.152
  ports:
  - name: node-1
    port: 7000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7000
  - name: node-2
    port: 7001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7000
  - name: node-3
    port: 7002
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7000
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I expected I could find the pods/deployment/or instances that actually serving the redis service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find IPs of pods that are serving this service using this command:

```
kubectl get endpoints dispatchcache-shard
```

After that you may find actual pods by IP addresses with this command:

```
kubectl get pod -o wide
```

I want to add that there should be very strong reason to define service without label selectors. Not sure this is your case.

Comment: Hi Valisy THanks for your answer. I did what you suggested. I got the Endpoints of dispatchcache-shard but when I run the second command to find the pods I got nothing. I put frep command as well to be sure but still no pods are using the IP address as defined in the dispatchcache-shard's endpoint

Comment: Then use "kubectl get pod -o wide --all-namespaces". If you won't find IPs even this time - then Redis endpoints are not running in Kubernetes. They may run somewhere else in your network.

Comment: Hi Vasily thanks for your answer again. I found them. It turned out they were not pods. They were VM instances which are outside kubernetes.

Comment: Accept an answer then.